# How to add rows to UITableView dynamically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Need the application to add rows dynamically to a TableView. How to implement that?

---

This doesn't seem to work:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [[NSIndexPath alloc]initWithIndex:(rowCount - 1)]; 
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:
    [NSArray arrayWithObject:path] withRowAnimation:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything - do you have any code to show us?

Comment: You have to add some level of detail to your question. Otherwise you can't get a good answer. Check out [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at:

```
-(void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths     
       withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

If you would have waited a while writing this question, you would have seen numerous 
suggestions for similar questions.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't works for me..  NSIndexPath *path = [[NSIndexPath alloc]initWithIndex:(rowCount - 1)];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:path] withRowAnimation:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];